# Term for someone who keeps rejecting ideas without specifying what they want

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, pejorative-language

Is there a particular word or phrase for when you keep giving suggestions and advice to someone about a broad topic and that person keeps rejecting the ideas but won't specifically say what they want to hear?

Example: During a brainstorming session, I offered a couple of ideas, which were dismissed. Months later, it turned out the group leader only intended to pursue one avenue. (I wish he would have said so at the meeting.)

What do you call a person who is deliberating coy about something and allowes others continue to labor under the illusion that they're being productive when they are secretively not really interested in suggestions that don't align with his idea?

Comment: I disagree with the (very uninformative, by the way) title of the question: there _isn’t_, to my knowledge, an idiomatic expression for that particular notion.

Comment: This is my first time using this website and I do not know the proper way of titling questions. I'll try to be more informative next time *shrugs*

Comment: The proper word would be "Naysayer"!

Comment: I don't think this question needs to be on hold, it can be answered as it is now.

Comment: It seems like I am not using this site correctly.  How do I erase my questions?

Comment: Hi Sparkledot. Reality is - IMO - new users are subject to a higher level of examination than seasoned users. And perhaps this is a good thing, as to maintain a high level of quality for this site. A good question here, should be asking something specific, and answerable. For what it's worth, I think both of your questions were reasonable, subject to a bit of editing.

Comment: I thought the original question (before it was edited) was perfectly good. So was the title. I have no idea why so many people have been having a problem with it. Questions here seem to be prone to over-moderation, just because some users have the power to over-moderate.

Comment: @ErikKowal Where the line between moderation and over-moderation should be drawn is a subject for the meta - Perhaps raise a question there?

Comment: [Related](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/word-for-disrespecting-eldest-half-sister-by-referring-to-her-husband-as-girly-g#comment16076_4732).

Comment: I think my wife has this syndrome whenever we're deciding what to eat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a single word term for how a person *with a* [*hidden agenda*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hidden+agenda) *behaves*. But your description was certainly informative and clear. We are all aware of how difficult it is to deal with people with hidden agendas.

They are difficult, confusing, frustrating, and at times quite discouraging. But so are a lot of other people for other reasons. Their motives may be complex, as well. So it cannot be that *one word* is set aside for this type or person.

However, you can describe the behavior. Off-putting. Discouraging. Confusing.

This kind of behavior is [*passive aggressive*](http://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/Passive+aggresive) "often overtly ambivalent, wavering indecisively from one course of action to its opposite" but indirectly pushing for what they desire. Sometimes in the church, this is the only acceptable means of asserting oneself because of the self-denial that is expected. In these cases, the people are behaving passive-aggressively, **not** displaying a *passive aggressive personality disorder.*

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd call him an *asshole with a hidden agenda*.

But that may not be what you're after, so as alternatives I suggest *saboteur, sabotager*, and *underminer*.

Comment: Isn't that what you call politicians too?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I'd call most of them by worse names than that, but then I'd probably get kicked off the site. :-)